# why is submit onclick not working when its inside the form?

Tags: css, forms, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

This form uses react-bootstrap styling. The submit button breaks and restarts the app in this form. When I move the button outside of the form tag it works. What is the reason? I would like to keep the button in the form tag for styling.

```
       <Form>
          <Form.Row>
            <Col xs={9}>
            <Form.Group>
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend">@</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                placeholder="Username"
                aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                name="username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  console.log(`${this.state.username}`);
                  this.setState({username: event.target.value});
                }}
                required
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                Please choose a username.
              </Form.Control.Feedback>

            </InputGroup>
            </Form.Group>
            </Col>
            <Col>
            <Button variant="primary" 
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={() => {
                      try {
                        console.log("Submit button clicked");
                      } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                      }
                    }}>
              Submit
            </Button>
            </Col>
          </Form.Row>
        </Form>
```

Comment: Check your browser Inspector for javascript errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks and restarts the app" any way? A submit button generates a submit event for the form. Sounds like it's doing its job.

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing the button’s type from “submit” to “button”. Or remove the type param all-together. Currently, a submit type button allows the form to execute onSubmit ignoring the button’s own onClick.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the onClick event overwrites the type=“submit“ functionality. Resulting in only the onClick event gets fired.

You probably don‘t need the answer anymore, but i just came across the same problem.